# Overriding WooCommerce CSS?

Tags: css, plugins

I have Woocommerce installed on a site I am prototyping. I have some Woocommerce CSS I want to change, but when I try to change it via the style.css in my Twenty Eleven child theme, nothing happens. I can make the change in Firebug no problem.

I assume it's because the plugin CSS is being loaded after the theme CSS. I tried marking the CSS changes with !important but that yielded no results.

the CSS:

```
ul.products li.product{
    width: 48% !important;
}
```

the purpose: to make the 2 column layout full width

Answer (score 4):

You can change the CSS loading order.

Find the place where WooCommerce enqueues it's CSS and keep in mind it's `$handle` (name). Search for `wp_enqueue_style`.

Then go to theme's `functions.php` and find the place where your theme enqueues it's CSS.

Now change your theme's `wp_enqueue_style` by adding WooCommerce's `$handle` to `$deps` (dependencies) parameter of theme's `wp_enqueue_style`.

After these manipulations WordPress will load theme CSS after WooCommerce CSS, which will become overridable.

For example:

```
<?php
wp_register_style(
    'your-theme-css', // theme CSS handle (name)
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-theme.css', // theme CSS path
    array('woocommerce-css-handle') // dependencies
);
```

Comment: where 'woocommerce-css-handle' is probably 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' (looking at page source on a site with WooCommerce).

Answer (score 1):

you could try being more specific:

```
#content .products .product{
    width: 48% !important;
}
```